# Gaussian Copulas: My Marginal Distribution Includes Negatives but My Copula is Non-Negative?

Tags: monte-carlo, correlation, simulations, copula, kendall-tau

Attempting Copula in R for Stock Returns, Bond Returns, and Inflation Rates. This is my first attempt with Copulas but I have looked many places and cannot determine what I'm doing wrong. My Marginal Distribution for Stock Returns includes negatives but my copula is non-negative? I studied math in college but somehow didn't get into stats outside of probability theory so I realize I may be making a very obvious mistake. I appreciate any help!

**Here are my samples:**

**> EQ**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJvav.png)  0.2577 -0.0973  0.1476  0.1727  0.0140  0.2633  0.1462  0.0203  0.1240  0.2725 -0.0656  0.2631  0.0446  0.0706 -0.0154  0.3411  0.2026  0.3101  0.2667  0.1953
[21] -0.1014 -0.1304 -0.2337  0.2638  0.0899  0.0300  0.1362  0.0353 -0.3849  0.2345  0.1278  0.0000  0.1341  0.2960  0.1139 -0.0073  0.0954  0.1942 -0.0624  0.2888
[41]  0.1626

**> FI**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJvav.png)  0.0271  0.0626  0.3265  0.0819  0.1515  0.2213  0.1530  0.0275  0.0789  0.1453  0.0896  0.1600  0.0740  0.0975 -0.0292  0.1846  0.0364  0.0964  0.0870 -0.0082
[21]  0.1163  0.0843  0.1026  0.0410  0.0434  0.0243  0.0433  0.0697  0.0524  0.0593  0.0654  0.0784  0.0422 -0.0202  0.0597  0.0055  0.0265  0.0354 -0.0005  0.0898
[41]  0.0732

**> INF**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJvav.png) 0.125 0.089 0.038 0.038 0.039 0.038 0.011 0.044 0.044 0.046 0.061 0.031 0.029 0.027 0.027 0.025 0.033 0.017 0.016 0.027 0.034 0.016 0.024 0.019 0.033 0.034 0.025
[28] 0.041 0.001 0.027 0.015 0.030 0.017 0.015 0.008 0.007 0.021 0.021 0.019 0.023 0.012

**I create the multivariate normal distribution:**
z <- mvrnorm(5000,mu=rep(0, 3),Sigma=sigma,empirical=T)

**My Covariance Matrix:**

```
         Stocks         Bonds     Inflation
```

Stocks    0.0249320710 1.823011e-03 1.782424e-04

Bonds     0.0018230106 4.504779e-03 9.501098e-05

Inflation 0.0001782424 9.501098e-05 4.711988e-04

**Converting above to Kendall Tau:**

cor(z,method='kendall')

```
       [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
```

[1,] 1.00000000 0.10960080 0.04068798

[2,] 0.10960080 1.00000000 0.04049146

[3,] 0.04068798 0.04049146 1.00000000

**I then covert to the Uniform Distribution:**

u <- pnorm(z)

**I apply the marginal distributions:**

**Skew Normal for Stock Returns**
x1 <- qsn(u[,1], 0.30184549, 0.2588313, -3.791324)

**Asymmetric Laplace for Bond Returns**
x2 <- qALD(u[,2], 0.05929170, 0.02179876, 0.40287827)

**Asymmetric Laplace for Inflation**
X3 <- qALD(u[,3], 0.018981966, 0.004905255, 0.271608939)

**Here's my final result that has no negatives?...**
[image]

**But my Skew Normal simulated stock returns sample looks like this:**

[image]